I need a permenant solution beacuse every time i am facing the below issue
Installing template dependencies using npm.
npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm error
npm error While resolving: demo@0.1.0
npm error Found: react@19.0.0
npm error node_modules/react
npm error   react@"^19.0.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.4.0
npm error node_modules/@testing-library/react
npm error   @testing-library/react@"^13.0.0" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm error
npm error
npm error For a full report see:
npm error C:\Users\Classic\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-12-06T10_14_20_638Z-eresolve-report.txt
npm error A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\Classic\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2024-12-06T10_14_20_638Z-debug-0.log
`npm install --no-audit --save @testing-library/jest-dom@^5.14.1 @testing-library/react@^13.0.0 @testing-library/user-event@^13.2.1 web-vitals@^2.1.0` failed

I need a permenant solution for this
I am solving this manually by
npm install@latest 
npm i web-vitals


Stop using CRA, which is no longer maintained.

The error already contains the solution. You can use --force. Or update @testing-library/react and possibly other react-related deps to the latest versions that explicitly support 19

you can use yarn commands, it will resolve your problem.
